# How to open an output set that is a list of double values in a geoprocessing service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, c#, geoprocessing-service

we are trying to reduce the amount of data we are returning from the server by eliminating returning a polyline and instead returning a collection of values of type GPDouble.

When the transaction is kicked off inside our GeoProcessing Service via Execute, the first thing we do is create the parameters we are either going to process or return.  for example to get the target list we execute this code:

```
        IFeatureClass targetClass;
        filter = null;
        _gputilities.DecodeFeatureLayer(GPUtilities.GetParameterValueByName(parameterValues, "TargetList"), out targetClass, out filter);
        if (targetClass == null || targetClass.FeatureCount(null) == 0)
        {
            message.AddError(2, "Could not open Target input dataset.");
            return;
        }
        message.AddMessage("Target List has been defined.");
```

I changed my OutList parameter definition as follows (old definition commented out)

```
            //IGPParameterEdit3 outputPoints =
            //    GPUtilities.CreatePolylineRecordsetParameterEdit("OutputList", "Output List", "MsramSDE.DBO.Standard_Polyline",
            //        esriGPParameterDirection.esriGPParameterDirectionOutput,
            //        esriGPParameterType.esriGPParameterTypeDerived, new GPFeatureRecordSetLayerTypeClass(), true);
            IGPParameterEdit3 outputPoints = GPUtilities.CreateParameterEdit("OutputList", "Output List", 
                esriGPParameterDirection.esriGPParameterDirectionOutput,
                esriGPParameterType.esriGPParameterTypeDerived, new GPDoubleTypeClass(), true, "0.00");
            parameters.Add(outputPoints);
```

None of our other GeoProcessing Services return anything but a FeatureLayer.  So I lack any example and could not find one via Google for opening up an Output Item that gives me a way of writing out the double values.  Anyone ever done this and how do I do it?  I've looked through the GPUtilities calls to see if there was an obvious DecodeBaseType or some such call but could not find one.  Should this be defined as a record set instead?